# How do I do a one-shot MathOperator?

Tags: amsmath, math-operators

The amsmath packages helpfully define a macro `\DeclareMathOperator` which does what it says on the tin: it declares a mathematical operator such as `\sin` or `\Null` or whatever and typesets it all nice and dandy.

If I want to do a one-shot operator, it seems a bit of a fuss to `\DeclareMathOperator` it if I'm only going to use it once. So:

Is there a command that typesets its contents in the same way that `\DeclareMathOperator` does?  (And I'd like it to be *exactly* how `\DeclareMathOperator` does since I sometimes mess with fonts and colours and would like them consistent.)

Comment: What do you mean by `\Null`?

Comment: @LoverofStructure (Firstly, I'd've put that link as a *comment* rather than adding to the question.)  I mean that I can do `\DeclareMathOperator{\Null}{Null}` to allow me to write `\Null` in the document.  I generally use it for the null space of a matrix or linear transformation.  As I often teach linear algebra I use it quite a lot so I use `\DeclareMathOperator` to define it.  But sometimes there's something that I'll only use once (see my comment on Yiannis' answer), hence this question.

Comment: Related: [What is the difference of \mathop, \operatorname and \DeclareMathOperator?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/84302/14996)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You are looking for `\mathop`: http://www.giss.nasa.gov/tools/latex/stackrel.html , for example `\mathop{\sum \sum}_{i,j=1}^{N} a_i a_j`.

If you really want to do exactly what amsmath does then `\operatorname` is a better choice.

Comment: TeX in space?! Something new every day..

Comment: `\mathop` doesn't seem to make its argument `\mathrm` as is default for operators. I think the right approach is to use `\operatorname` and then, if you need subscripts etc, wrap that in a `\mathop`

Comment: @Seamus see my post below for font.

Comment: @Seamus `\operatorname*` is the variant you need if you want to have limits.

Comment: You can even try this `[\operatornamewithlimits{K}_{k=0}^\infty\frac{a_k}{b_k}\]`

Answer (score 9):

You can go back to the TeXbook and do it the Knuth way, using `\mathop`

```
\def\limsup{\mathop{\overline{\rm lim}}}

\[\limsup\]
```

**Edit**

If you really only want a one shot, you can type:

```
\[\mathop{\overline{lim}}_{n=1}\limits\]
```

I would rather have something like:

```
\def\oneshot#1{\mathop{\mathrm{#1}}\limits}

\[\oneshot{Diag}_{n=1}^m\]
```

One can extend the command `\oneshot` to the `\nolimits` version for consistency. Why I prefer a two shot approach i.e, defining it first and then using it, is that good software practice dictates that you should try and re-use code. You could stick the command in your master style file, if you have one. It will also with a shorter name make reading the LaTeX source easier.

Would you really use an operator only once in a mathematics write-up?

Comment: if you're using latex, better to use `\mathrm`: `\def\limsup{\mathop{\overline{\mathrm{lim}}}}` or just look into the file `amsopn.sty` and see how `\DeclareMathOperator` is defined.  it's a bit convoluted, but you're good enough at latex innards to figure it out.  do take note of the use of `\limits'.

Comment: @Yiannis: It doesn't really make sense to wrap this in a `\def` (or better `\newcommand`): As the title says, this is about a _one-shot_ math operator.

Comment: @Hendrik Vogt For a one shot one can only use `\overline{lim}` if you are not too worried about side-effects, or `\mathop{\overline{lim}}`. I wouldn't use `newcommand` in this case as `def` can be overwritten much easier and is less typing. One-shot is not a recommended approach from a programming perspective, so I would recommend one takes two shots!

Comment: @Yiannis: Sorry, but I find it _really_ doesn't make sense what you're saying here. I have the feeling that sometimes you need to read the questions more carefully: "it seems a bit of a fuss to `\DeclareMathOperator` it if I'm only going to use it once". And what would be the advantage of your solution over `\DeclareMathOperator`??

Comment: @Hendrik Vogt Only advantage is that you don't need `amsmath`. Another is that you do not need to define it as with the `DeclareMathOperator` in the preamble only. See also my edited answer for some more thoughts on the subject.

Comment: @Yiannis: I like your edited answer _much_ better: You _explain_ why you chose to not make it a one-shot. Thanks a lot!

Comment: To answer your last question: the case in point was that I was explaining alternative notation, so I wanted to say something like `\(\colspan(A)\) is also sometimes written \(\oneshot{col}(A)\)`, whereupon I would never refer to `\col` again but always use `\colspan`.