# What is the difference of \mathop, \operatorname and \DeclareMathOperator?

Tags: best-practices, math-operators

One sees all kind of versions in source files for defining something like a limit etc. So my question is which one serves what purpose. Is there any "best practice" in chosing one over the other?

Comment: Related: [How do I do a one-shot MathOperator?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12653/14996)

Comment: Related https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/546641/what-is-the-difference-between-the-several-definitions-of-mathematic-operators/546642#546642

Comment: [**TL;DR:**](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/84305/2930)   `$\mathop{\mathrm{max}}$`   is a primitive version of   `$\operatorname{max}$`   which is equivalent to   `\DeclareMathOperator{\max}{max}` `$\max$`.

Answer (score 133, accepted):

When is it better to use `\operatorname` (or its wrapper `\DeclareMathOperator`) instead of `\mathop`? The answer is easy: always, unless you know precisely what's the behavior of `\mathop`.

---

First of all, one must of course recall that `\operatorname` and `\DeclareMathOperator` are provided by the `amsopn` package, which is automatically loaded by `amsmath`, but is also available standalone.

Let's see the main definitions:

```
\DeclareRobustCommand{\operatorname}{%
  \@ifstar{\qopname\newmcodes@ m}%
          {\qopname\newmcodes@ o}}%
\DeclareRobustCommand{\qopname}[3]{%
  \mathop{#1\kern\z@\operator@font#3}%
  \csname n#2limits@\endcsname}
\newcommand{\DeclareMathOperator}{%
  \@ifstar{\@declmathop m}{\@declmathop o}}
\long\def\@declmathop#1#2#3{%
  \@ifdefinable{#2}{%
    \DeclareRobustCommand{#2}{\qopname\newmcodes@#1{#3}}}}
```

The command `\qopname` is not really meant to be used in a document; the purpose of its first argument is to add some declarations such as `\newmcodes@` before typesetting the operator name.

The `\operatorname` and `\DeclareMathOperator` each have a *-variant that passes to `\qopname` a second argument `m` instead of `o`. The latter command is just a wrapper:

```
\DeclareMathOperator{\xyz}{xyz}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\XYZ}{XYZ}
```

are pretty much equivalent to saying

```
\DeclareRobustCommand{\xyz}{\operatorname{xyz}}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\XYZ}{\operatorname*{XYZ}}
```

(but treated more efficiently) so what we need to examine is just `\operatorname`.

A call of `\operatorname{xyz}` translates into

```
\qopname\newmcodes@ o {xyz}
```

which becomes

```
  \mathop{\newmcodes@\kern\z@\operator@font xyz}\csname nolimits@\endcsname}
```

1. The `\newmcodes@` declaration takes care that some characters are treated differently as usual in math formulas (in particular the hyphen doesn't become a minus sign);
2. `\kern\z@` inserts an invisible object so that the entire contents of `\mathop` will never be a single character (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/41267/4427 for details);
3. `\operator@fonts` chooses the predefined font for math operators, which usually is the upright text font;
4. `\nolimits@` is just an alias for `\nolimits`, so following subscripts and superscripts won't be typeset above and below the operator, unless countermanded by a `\limits` declaration.

For `\operatorname*` it's exactly the same, with the only difference that `\nmlimits@` will be executed instead of `\nolimits@`. This macro is defined to be equivalent to `\displaylimits`, which makes the operator behave like the standard `\lim` or `\min`.

If an operator is used just a couple of times in a document, one can maybe dispense with defining a command with `\DeclareMathOperator`; but readability of the source is, in my opinion, enhanced if proper names for logical structures are used.

For `\mathop` one has to remember that it doesn't choose any particular font and it doesn't correct some glitches: so the output of

```
\mathop{\mathrm{abc-def}}
```

will be rather different from

```
\operatorname{abc-def}
```

and the latter is usually expected. In some rare cases `\mathop` is useful by itself:

```
\newcommand{\diff}{\mathop{}\!d}
```

is an example, where the empty `\mathop` is used to provide the correct spacing before the "d". Note that if one really wants to have an upright "d", it would be incorrect to define it as `\operatorname{d}` and the same as before with `\mathrm{d}` instead of `d` should be used: explicitly, the alternative is

```
\newcommand{\diff}{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}}
```

Also `\stackrel` and the better `amsmath` commands `\overset` and `\underset` are defined with an internal `\mathop{...}\limits` but wrapped up in some other construction.

Comment: Why do you use `\mathop{}` to affect spacing, if you then get rid of the extra space provided with `\!`? Wouldn’t it be better to use just a single spacing modifier?

Comment: @DanielH With `\mathop` there are *two* thin spaces: one before and one after. The `\!` gets rid of the latter, but the former remains.

Comment: I figured that was part of it, but why not just use `\,` instead, which also has the total effect of a single thin space?

Comment: @DanielH The thin space is not wanted if you say `$\diff x$` or, more probably, `\frac{\diff f}{\diff x}`. Of course `\int f(x)\,dx` is shorter than `\int f(x)\diff x`; but when you have 100 integrals and 200 Leibniz derivatives in your document and your supervisor tells you that the “d” of the differential *must* be upright…

Comment: You’re right, of course. I’d found this page while thinking about integration only and got confused.

Comment: @egreg Is the definition of `\mathop` itself available anywhere?

Comment: @justin It's a TeX primitive

Comment: This sure is an excellent answer for any TeX buff. However, it would be even better for TeX-agnostics with a couple of visual examples.

Comment: In the definition of `\diff` I don't know why you remove the space before the symbol `d`.  Actually, the space needs to be removed _after_ `d`.

Comment: @MátéWierdl Not at all. If you try `$x\mathop{}dx$`, you'll see no space after `d`, but a double thin space between `x` and `d`.

Comment: I dunno how to insert latex code here.  Actually, what I do not understand is why it is incorrect to use `DeclareMathOperator` here.

Comment: @MátéWierdl Because you don't want a thin space between “d” and “x”. Try `$x\operatorname{d}x$`. But if you did `\newcommand{\diff}{\operatorname{d}\!}` then `$\diff(x+y)$` would came out wrong.

Comment: I have <code>\DeclareMathOperator{\diff}{d\!}</code>

Comment: @MátéWierdl Then try `\diff(x+y)`

Answer (score 40):

`\mathop` is the most primitive command, declaring the *class* of a character or subformula to be a *unary math operator* like `\sum`, for instance. This has consequences for spacing, compared to *binary operators* declared with `\mathbin` or *binary relations* declared with `\mathrel`, for instance.

Most math operators are written out as textual names. Some definitions from `latex.ltx`:

```
\def\max{\mathop{\operator@font max}}
\def\min{\mathop{\operator@font min}}
\def\sup{\mathop{\operator@font sup}}
\def\inf{\mathop{\operator@font inf}}
\def\arg{\mathop{\operator@font arg}\nolimits}
\def\ker{\mathop{\operator@font ker}\nolimits}
\def\dim{\mathop{\operator@font dim}\nolimits}
\def\hom{\mathop{\operator@font hom}\nolimits}
```

You see that a special font `\operator@font` is used; furthermore, one can see that an operator declared with `\mathop` is usually typeset *with limits*, that is, super- and subscripts are placed in a special position in displaymode. This can be turned off with `\nolimits`.

`\operatorname` from the AMSTeX bundle encapsulates this as a user command:

```
\DeclareRobustCommand{\operatorname}{%
  \@ifstar{\qopname\newmcodes@ m}%
          {\qopname\newmcodes@ o}}%
\DeclareRobustCommand{\qopname}[3]{%
  \mathop{#1\kern\z@\operator@font#3}%
  \csname n#2limits@\endcsname}
```

This basically means that `\operatorname{dual}` will typeset a math operator "dual" which looks like `\arg` (i.e. without limits) and `\operatorname*{dual}` will typeset a math operator "dual" which looks like `\max` (i.e. with limits).

`\DeclareMathOperator` is the corresponding declaration, i.e. `\DeclareMathOperator\dual{dual}` creates a new macro `\dual` which works like `\max`.

On usage:

- With `\mathop`, anything can be declared a math operator, i.e. if you want to use `*` like a prefix operator (with limits), you can just say `\mathop{*}`.
- `\DeclareMathOperator` should be used if you want to define a new operator like `\max`.
- `\operatorname` should be used for special cases where you need a special operator name only once.

Comment: You mixed up what the asterisk does.

Comment: @peter Indeed. Edited.

Comment: @StephanLehmke awesome answers!

Answer (score 19):

`\mathop` is a plainTeX command, which declares a big operator like

```
\newcommand{\Res}{\mathop{\hbox{Res}}}
```

`DeclareMathOperator` is from AmsMath's `amsopn` subpackage, called as:

```
\DeclareMathOperator{\Res}{Res}
```

whereas `operatorname` is kind of an operator "on-the-fly". Input of

```
\operatorname{Res}
```

has the same meaning as `\Res` defined with `mathop` or `DeclareMathOperator`

I think, if you loaded AmSMath (always a good idea) then I would use `DeclareMathOperator` and `operatorame` in cases this operator is seldom used in the file or to make some text in math-mode upright and with space-padding.