# How to use \limits to place superscripts directly above or subscripts directly below large math symbols?

Tags: math-mode

I have used `\limits` in `\[\bigcup\limits_{\i \in I}\]` in order to make subscripts displayed in bottom of `\bigcup`.

However, it looked the same as `\[\bigcup_{\i \in I}\]`. I.e. it didn't work.

Why? Didn't I used it in the correct way?

---

Update
MWE:

```
\documentclass{aomart}

\DeclareMathOperator{\Union}{\mathop{\bigcup}}
\begin{document}
\[\Union\limits_{i \in I}\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: As you are already in displaystyle math mode (using `\[ \]`), `\[\bigcup_{\i \in I}\]` should result in subscript underneath the symbol as expected. Can you give a full MWE?

Comment: As Corentin says your example should work.  Can you post a complete  [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) so we can see which documentclass and packages your a using.

Comment: @AndrewSwann Okay,no problem.

Comment: @Corentin Okay, I have done.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel Yes, it does. Btw, what are differences between `\DeclareMathOperator*` and `\DeclareMathOperator`?

Comment: With `\bigcup` it works perfectly; if you want a new name for it, just do `\newcommand{\Union}{\bigcup}`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From the `amsmath` documentation (`texdoc --view amsldoc.pdf`):

> If the new operator should have subscripts and superscripts placed in “limits”
>   position above and below as with lim, sup, or max, use the `*` form of the `\DeclareMathOperator` command:
>
> ```
> \DeclareMathOperator*{\Lim}{Lim}
> ```

Also, the `\mathop` is not needed. After all, you *declare* a *math operator* with `\DeclareMathOperator[*]`.

I refer to „[What is the difference of `\mathop`, `\operatorname` and `\DeclareMathOperator`?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/84302/16595)“ for further reading on this topic.

```
\DeclareMathOperator*{\<new op>}{<stuff that should be typeset as an op with limits>}
```

---

This answers the question why the limits aren’t where you have expected them to be.

**But `\bicup` is already an operator you should do**

```
\newcommand*{\Union}{\bigcup}
```

instead to have a more descriptive name for it (which is a good idea nonetheless)**.**

The `\DeclareMathOperator*` pair of macros is to declare *new* operators like the already defined `\lim`, `\sum`, and so on.

### Code

```
\documentclass{aomart}
\newcommand*{\Union}{\bigcup}

\begin{document}
\[ \Union_{i \in I} \bigcup_{i \in I} \]
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image] [image]

Comment: I don't think I'd recommand `\DeclareMathOperator*` for this.

Comment: @egreg I hope the updated answer differentiates better between what has been done wrong regarding the use of `\DeclareMathOperator` and  what has been done wrong with `\bigcup`.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel Yes, it seems good