# If a math operator doesn't exist, type it as text in a certain font

Tags: math-mode, macros

Is it possible to have some kind of condition where, if you type an operator in math mode and it doesn't exist, it types it as text in a certain font?

In particular, when I write complexity papers I often want to use the `\mathsf` font for the myriad of abbreviations in the field. The `complexity` package does OK, but is missing a lot of stuff which I then manually declare with `\DeclareMathOperator`. If this "else" statement existed for operators, that would be incredibly useful.

Comment: `\newcommand*\complexityoperator[1]{\mathop{\mathsf{#1}}}`?

Comment: @HenriMenke I'd use `\operatorname` instead of `\mathop`, but that's the idea.

Comment: @egreg Isn’t `\operatorname` more or less just `\mathop{\operator@font#1}`?

Comment: @HenriMenke No, it's much more. See http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/84308/4427

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You shouldn't use `\mathsf` anyway. The `complexity` package defines

```
\lang
\func
\class
```

along with `\newlang`, `\newfunc` and `\newclass`. So, if you have the class QQ, you should either use `\class{QQ}` or do

```
\newclass{\QQ}{QQ}
```

(the command name can be chosen arbitrarily, provided it is not already taken) in the preamble and use `\QQ` in the document.

In this way you ensure that changing the options to the package will be honored by your commands.

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{complexity}

\newclass{\Q}{Q}
\newclass{\NQ}{NQ}

\begin{document}

I propose two new problems: $\Q\ne\NQ$
and $\class{BBC}=\class{BBQ}$.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Fair enough. I will follow the rules :p