# Math \vdash with top and down index

Tags: math-mode, math-operators

I'd like to know ow can i type this symbol like on image in math mode.

[image: \Vdash with indexes]

Thank you a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're interested in declaring a new math operator. For this, there exists `\DeclareMathOperator` (provided by [`amsmath`](//ctan.org/pkg/amsmath)):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\DeclareMathOperator*{\VDash}{\vdash}

\begin{document}

See $\VDash_M^*$, or
\[
  \VDash_M^* abc.
\]

\end{document}
```

Also see [What is the difference of `\mathop`, `\operatorname` and `\DeclareMathOperator`?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/84302/5764) for other options if you don't want to *declare* a new term.

Comment: Thank you, but i need it inside of the text like

`$(q_0,\Delta \omega \Delta^\omega, 0) \Vdash_M^* abc (q_f, \gamma, n)$`

Comment: @Oggy: Sure, use `$\displaystyle (q_0,\Delta \omega \Delta^\omega, 0) \Vdash_M^* abc (q_f, \gamma, n)$`. Of course, this will affect the line height.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this at TeX level:

```
\def\Vdash{\mathop{\vdash}}

$\Vdash_M^* abc$ and
$$
  \Vdash_M^* abc.
$$

\bye
```