# Place the start and end index above and below the symbol ||

Tags: math-mode, symbols, overleaf

I use this command

```
$$E = \parallel_{i=1}^{8}E_i$$
```

to get this result:

[image]

But I would like the start and end indexes to be above and below, not overwritten and subscribed, like this:

[image]

I found this thread, but I'm not understanding what I'm doing wrong that doesn't work:
[Math \vdash with top and down index](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/419833/math-vdash-with-top-and-down-index)

```
\DeclareMathOperator{8}{\Parallel}{\parallel}
  
$$ E = \parallel_{i=1}^{8}E_i $$
\[
  \Parallel_{i=1}^{8}E_i
\]
```

Comment: You may want to use `\DeclareMathOperator*`. But the `{8}` is completely out of place

Comment: I tried to replicate what was in that discussion. Instead of the '{8}' was the '*' that stood on top

Answer (score 1):

I don't quite understand the syntax, but I was able to solve using this feature directly in the text:

```
\def\Parallel{\mathop{\parallel}}
 
$$
  E = \Parallel_{i=1}^8 E_i
$$
```