# Sans-Serif Font using Metropolis Theme and Physics Package

Tags: beamer, fonts, beamer-metropolis, physics

using the `beamer` class theme `metropolis`, I stumbled over the `physics` package's `\dv{}` command. This MWE illustrates the issue:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{metropolis}
\usepackage{physics}
\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        Usual math is sans-serif: $12 + 4 = x^2$.

        Physics package not necessarily: $\dv{x}{y} \neq \pdv{i}{k}$.
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Usually, the theme takes good care of its math font and typesetting everything sans-serif. Yet, the physics package seems to use a completely different, serif font. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `physics` packages uses `\mathrm` in the definition of `\diffd`, this will force serif font even if the rest of the presentation is in sans serif. You could change the definition of `\diffd`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{moloch}% modern fork of the metropolis theme
\usepackage{physics}


\def\diffd{\textup{d}}


\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        Usual math is sans-serif: $12 + 4 = x^2$.

        Physics package not necessarily: $\dv{x}{y} \neq \pdv{i}{k}$.
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: According to [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/84308), it seems better to use this definition for `\diffd`: `\def\diffd{\mathop{}\!\mathsf{d}}`. Compare space before dx with your definition and with mine, in `$I=\int_a^b f(x)\dd x$`.

Comment: @quark67 That's the way the `physics` package defines it. I'm not going to challenge that there are better ways to define it.