# Automatically separate blocks by space in mathmode

Tags: math-mode, spacing

I have a document with equations containing many mathematically not strictly necessary brackets.
These brackets are customary in order to simplify the identification of certain blocks of the equations.
However, they also bring a lot of noise into the document.
I was considering to replace the brackets with a spaces around these blocks.
In order to play around with this idea I want to define a macro that defines something like a new math atom that ensures that there is a space whenever two of these new atoms are next to each other or next to a mathord atom.
However, when this new atom is next to a mathrel, mathbin or another of the usual math atoms it should just behave like a mathord.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
The $abc$ and $def$ are distinct blocks within the equations.
They are highlighted using brackets.
\[y = x (abc)(def) z\]
\[y = (abc) x + (def) xz\]

I would like to automatically highlight them with spaces using a macro.
The outcome should look similar to this.
\[y = x \;\, abc \;\, def \;\, z\]
\[y = abc \;\, x + def \;\, xz\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Are these “blocks” normal math symbols stuck together by multiplication or “strings of letters”?

Comment: Its all math connected by omitted operators, no text involved.

Comment: This looks like `\mathop` spacing, with a larger `\thinmuskip`. Alas, you can only have one value of `\thinmuskip` in a formula.

Comment: Yes this is roughly, what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`\mathinner` does about what I was looking for.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\block}[1]{\mathinner{#1}}
\begin{document}
The $abc$ and $def$ are distinct blocks within the equations.
They are highlighted using brackets.
\[y = x (abc)(def) z\]
\[y = (abc) x + (def) xz\]
\[y = x (abc) + xz (def)\]

I would like to automatically highlight them with spaces using a macro.
The outcome should look similar to this.
\[y = x \;\, abc \;\, def \;\, z\]
\[y = abc \;\, x + def \;\, xz\]
\[y = x \;\, abc + xz \;\, def \]
Hence
\[y = x \block{abc} \block{def} z\]
\[y = \block{abc} x + \block{def} xz\]
\[y = x \block{abc} + xz\block{def} \]
\end{document}
```

An alternative implementation with `\mathop` leads to problems in the last line.

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT**

By more testing (even after adding extra double braces), the answer was not correct when:

- The macro is followed by another similar macro
- The macro is followed by another operator (`+`, `-`, ...)

In both cases an extra thin space is added.

---

**Original Answer**

You can use `\operatorname` in the definition of your macro, instead of spaces `\,` `\;` ,... since the former has a  better control for inter spacing when two successive macros of this type are used, or when encountering another operator (`+`, `-`, `=`, etc).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand*{\distinctblock}[1]{{\operatorname\relax {#1} \operatorname\relax}}
%
\begin{document}
%
%
The $abc$ and $def$ are distinct blocks within the equations.
They are highlighted using \textbf{brackets}.
\[y = x (abc)(def) z\]
\[y = (abc) x + (def) xz\]

Highlighted using the custom command \textbf{distinctblock}

\[y = x \distinctblock{abc} \distinctblock{def} z\]
\[y = \distinctblock{abc} x + \distinctblock{def} xz\]
%
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is this different from `\mathop{}`?

Comment: @Donald Arseneau Here is a better explanation of the difference than I would ever do!! https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/84308/91556

Comment: This macro adds roughly the space I was looking for, but is also adds some space when used after a mathrel or a mathop, which I would like to avoid.

Comment: @hesham yes but as egreg explains there the difference is mostly about setting the argument in a suitable font, but as your argument is just `\relax` I think it doesn't do anything here.

Comment: @David Carlisle As I understand, the  `\operatorname` has two effects, changing of font style and adjusting spacing. If the `\relax` argument is removed, the `\operatorname` will affect the argument in question `abc` by changing its font style to operator fonts style (no longer math font style, i.e. behaves like `sin` and `cos` ops) in addition to changing the spacing. The OP is requiring adjusting the spacing only, hence `\relax` was inserted.

Comment: @Jan Hajer You are right and I tested it by adding `+` after the macro, then the `+` sign became very close to the next symbols. I will look into it. Meanwhile, of course any suggestions from anyone is welcomed.

Comment: @hesham \operatorname{\relax} is basically the same as \operatorname{} and given that the font setup is not used in that case, it is basically the same as \mathop{}