# What is the difference between the several definitions of mathematic operators?

Tags: math-mode, amsmath, math-operators

I am defining a new math operator, and I found that I can define it using 4 different commands:

- `\DeclareMathOperator` (package `amsmath`)
- `\operatorname` (package `amsmath`)
- `\DeclareMathOperator*` (package `amsmath`)
- `\mathop` (TeX command)

What is the formatting difference between them?

Comment: This is mostly covered in https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/84302/4427

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the MWE below, we see that the main differences are following:

- The operator's font changes: all commands write an **upright** operator, but `\mathop` write it *slanted*.
- In **display mode** both `\DeclareMathOperator*`  and `\mathop` set sub- and superscripts right below and above the operator, while the other operators set them shifted to the right.
- The operator stands right on the **baseline** for all commands but  for`\mathop` there it sinks below it (both in inline and display mode)

See picture and code below:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

%All operators are declared as commands
\DeclareMathOperator{\Ti}{T}
\newcommand{\Tii}{\operatorname{T}}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\Tiii}{T}
\newcommand{\Tiv}{\mathop{T}}

\begin{document}

%DeclareMathOperator
\verb|\DeclareMathOperator|\\
Inline:
\(x \Ti^a_b y\)
\\
Display:
\[x \Ti^a_b y\]

%Operatorname
\verb|\operatorname|\\
Inline:
\(x \Tii^a_b y\)
\\
Display:
\[x \Tii^a_b y\]

%DeclareMathOperator*
\verb|\DeclareMathOperator*|\\
Inline:
\(x \Tiii^a_b y\)
\\
Display:
\[x \Tiii^a_b y\]

%Mathop
\verb|\mathop|\\
Inline:
\(x \Tiv^a_b y\)
\\
Display:
\[x \Tiv^a_b y\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: you are just missing use of fonts and `\limits` in the primitive `\mathop`  but this answer misses the more subtle technical differences such as the different behaviour of single-ketter operators `\operatorname` is essentially `\mathop{\mathrm{`  with or without the use of `\limits` depending on `*`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle thanks for your experienced feedback. I think the answer is a first good guideline for beginners-intermediate users. I wrote what it first was evident to me. Please, add another answer with the deepest technical differences for advanced users. :) Of course you may edit my answer, but I think, that would spoil the **simplicity** and **clearness**. :-\

Comment: note that T is vertically centered with mathop not on the baseline

Comment: beginners shouldn't be using TeX primitives in latex documents:-)

Comment: But they surely do! And even find them in the code of others ;-) By the way, I added your information about the *baseline*, thanks!

Comment: only single character operators are vertically centred (so `\sum` works)  `\operatorname` is `\mathop{\mathrm{{}#1}}`  so it is never considered single character, plus some special handling of mathcodes, compare `\mathop{\mathrm{foo-bar}}` to `\operatorname{foo-bar}`