# Mimicking the spacing of DeclareMathOperator

Tags: spacing

I would like to mimic the spacing behavior of DeclareMathOperator without using a macro. I would like there to be a space after Spec when I write (in math mode)

> \mathrm{Spec} k.

But I would like there to be no space after Spec when I write

> \mathrm{Spec} (k).

Is there a way to do this? Sort of like \xspace but not in a macro.

Comment: Without using any macro whatsoever, not even \mathrm?

Comment: \mathrm is okay, I would like to avoid defining my own macros though (or at least only define one, rather than one for every operator)

Comment: I guess `\operatorname{Spec}` would be the easy solution (assuming the ubiquitous `amsmath`), see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/84302/35864

Comment: What do you have against \DeclareMathOperator?

Comment: I've written something and learned that I'm not supposed to define my own macros, so I need to change all the \Spec's to something.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With amsmath package loaded

```
\[ \operatorname{Spec} k - \operatorname{Spec} (k) \]
```

or without amsmath

```
\[ \mathop{\mathrm{Spec}} k - \mathop{\mathrm{Spec}} (k) \]
```

If you ever want superscripts or subscripts with the primitive \mathop, you should add \nolimits

```
\[ \mathop{\mathrm{Spec}}\nolimits^2 k - \mathop{\mathrm{Spec}} (k^2) \]
```

Comment: Punctuation `*-/:'` will also behave differently in `\operatorname`.