# $\sin{x}$ or $\mathrm{sin}\ x$

Tags: math-mode

I have been answering questions on Math S.E as well as Physics S.E.

Today I was pointed out for using `\mathrm` instead of using `\sin` by a fellow user.

So my question stands that, which of them is more visually appropriate for a reader and more acceptable:

## 1. $\sin t$

## 2. $\mathrm{sin}\ t$

as represented below:

[image: sinsinati]

To me, both of them look the same, what's the rendering difference (any helpful documentation)?

Comment: `$\sin t$`. It's easier, and TeX knows that it is an operator, so the spacing is better. Try for example to typeset `$\sin^{2} t$`.

Comment: Also try `$x\sin t$` versus `$x \mathrm{sin}\ t$`.  Spacing is way different.  `\sin t` is designed to produce the "proper" spacing.  `\mathrm{sin}` is just a simple math atom, whereas `\sin` spaces like a math operator.

Comment: The space between the sin and t are a bit smaller with the correct `\sin t` because `\sin` is not only in mathrm but is also defined as a math operator.

Comment: Note that Math.SE and Physics.SE do not literally use (La)TeX for maths typesetting, they use MathJax, which supports TeX-like input, but does not process the formulae with TeX. There may be some small differences in details between MathJax and real TeX and it is not completely inconceivable that these differences come to light in a setting like this. The answers you will get here will quite probably focus on (La)TeX and may be slightly different from what MathJax gives you (MathJax is generally considered off-topic here).

Comment: \mathrm{sin}\ x and \sin{t} look same (Indentation as well)

Comment: @moewe I have considered that as well, but it seems to me that my mathrm version (which has proper indent) is the fullform of \sin{t} ....is it the case?

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes yes, and the "sin" when looked closely also looks different, is there a proper script documentation available on it?

Comment: Leslie Lamport's book, "LaTeX: A document Preparation System" talks about math operators, including `\sin` on p.44-45.  As to the font itself, I would not see a reason why it would be different, if that is what you are implying.

Comment: The LaTeX standard definition of `\sin` is a bit more complicated than `\mathrm{sin}`. It follows the math operators explained in https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/84302/35864

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Yes I exactly imply that

Comment: @moewe probably just what am looking for, thanks, I'll have a look

Comment: Standard LaTeX has `\DeclareRobustCommand\sin{\mathop{\operator@font sin}\nolimits}` but most people will use `amsmath` which has `\def\sin{\qopname\relax o{sin}}` and then you need to chase `\DeclareRobustCommand{\qopname}[3]{%
  \mathop{#1\kern\z@\operator@font#3}%
  \csname n#2limits@\endcsname}`

Comment: "What does it look like" is a red herring. $\mathrm{s}\phantom{hello general Kenobi}\mathrm{in}\ t$ looks the same as your two options visually, but you'd be (correctly) reprimanded for using it. Clean coding, searchability, etc. also play a role.

Comment: By the way, I keep seeing `|\sin x|` which typesets badly and should be `\lvert\sin x\rvert`

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Compare:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\[ x\sin^{2} (t) + x\cos^{2} (t) = x\]
\[ x\mathrm{sin}^{2}\ (t) + x\mathrm{cos}^{2}\ (t) = x\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

in my opinion, the first option is much clearer.

Comment: aa, noo, add an escape sequence before xsin^2

Comment: x\ \sin^2{t} like this

Comment: If you look minutely, there's a difference between character width too, but does latex uses a different script for this??

Comment: @AnindyaPrithvi The idea is that proper math spacing is a difficult matter that requires a lot of work if done manually; however it follows a (not very easy) set of rules, which are so hardwired in TeX; using `\sin` exploits the rules and you have not to worry about adding spaces manually.

Comment: Indeed, OP, if you ever write TeX with another co-author, you will cause them so many headaches if you use cumbersome, imperfect, and easy to get wrong versions of standard commands like this.

Comment: Small nitpick: when using parentheses for the argument, there shouldn't be a space between sin/cos and the parentheses, or at least it should be smaller.

Comment: why did you put explicit spaces "\ " in the second formula but not the first? makes for a useless comparison...

Comment: i dont get it. they shouldn't be there or at least they should be on both versions. what sense does it make to compare two things that were manually made different?

Comment: @peter please look at the question. The extra `\ ` space is **in the question**, so I answered using the question as a base, comparing between them. If you think that's not the correct way, you are free to add another answer.

Comment: you're right, im sorry. i forgot that aspect and thought it was only about \mathrm{sin} vs \sin. my bad.

Comment: @peter no problem

Answer (score 4):

Considering also my registration on Math.SE., any user can adopt the long notation `\operatorname{...}` (eq. n. `(3)`) which provides the same white spaces as the formula n. `(2)`. `\operatorname{...}` can be used to define any mathematical operator, with the correct spaces, when yo're using `MathJaX`.

You can observe that the `(2)` (it has been used `\sin` and `\cos` operators) and for the `(3)` `\operatorname{...}` and they are the same. It is visible that using `\mathrm{sin}` with severals `\`, you have note the correct blank spaces.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{xcolor}


\begin{document}
\noindent Limited spaces for the operators:
\[\color{red}{\mathrm{sin}(\alpha+\beta)=\mathrm{sin}\alpha\mathrm{cos}\beta+\mathrm{cos}\alpha\mathrm{sin}\beta} \tag{1}\]
Correct spaces for the operators:
\[\color{green}{\sin(\alpha+\beta)=\sin\alpha\cos\beta+\cos\alpha\sin\beta} \tag{2}\]
Correct spaces for the operators: same of the previous code:
\[\color{green}{\operatorname{sin}(\alpha+\beta)=\operatorname{sin}\alpha\operatorname{cos}\beta+\operatorname{cos}\alpha\operatorname{sin}\beta} \tag{3}\]
Additional spaces given by the control \verb| \ | showing a bad spacing:
\[\color{red}{\mathrm{sin}(\alpha+\beta)=\mathrm{sin} \ \alpha \ \mathrm{cos} \ \alpha+ \mathrm{sin}\ \alpha \ \mathrm{cos} \ \alpha}\tag{4}\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: you missed the escape sequence... $\mathrm{sin} \ \alpha \ mathrm{cos} \ alpha$ `$\mathrm{sin} \ \alpha \ mathrm{cos} \ alpha$`

Comment: @AnindyaPrithvi Thank you very much and...I have added your example.

Comment: welcome, p.s. you did an incorrect expansion in the last step, but that's okay as far as latex is concerned

Comment: @AnindyaPrithvi Very kind user, for my opinion the best answer is that of Rmano user. Please, can you give the check answer to him?

Comment: I added yours as correct considering the fact that it emphasized what I offered. Both are equally acceptable

Comment: Let us give to Caesar what is Caesar's  :-):-)

Comment: Et tu Sebastiano?

Comment: @AnindyaPrithvi I'm glad to help you...and any user.