# let tikzpicture environment cut into equation

Tags: tikz-pgf

Im new to the tikz package how can I have the arrow closer to the equal sign and can I have it align automatically?

[image: output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
$$\left(\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2}\text{d}x\right)^2=\int_{-\infty}^\infty\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2-y^2}\text{d}x\text{d}y$$

\hspace{3cm}
\begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw[<-](0.9,0.5) -- (0.9,0) -- (0,0) -- (0,-.5) node[anchor=north] {explanation};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done using `\tikzmarknode` from the `tikzmark` Ti*k*Z library. This command creates a Ti*k*Z node around basically whatever you want. Here, the equal sign is a good candidate given what you wish to do. The node can be accessed from a `tikzpicture` that uses the `remember picture` and `overlay` options. You need to compile twice because this technique relies on the `.aux` file.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}

% From egreg: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/84308/73317
\newcommand{\diff}{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}}

\begin{document}
\[ \left( \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} e^{-x^2} \diff x \right)^{\!2}
   \tikzmarknode{eqsign}{=}
   \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \!\!\!
     \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \! e^{-x^2-y^2} \diff x \diff y \]

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
  \draw[<-] (eqsign) ++ (0,-1ex) -- ++(0,-0.5) -- ++(-0.9,0) -- ++(0,-.5)
            node[anchor=north] {explanation};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

For an explanation of the `\tikznode` command see
[my answer to "How to add arrow in equations and matrix?"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/361392/110998).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows} % for arrow tip stealth'xpdf 
\newcommand\tikznode[3][]{%
  \tikz[remember picture,baseline=(#2.base)]
      \node[minimum size=0pt,inner sep=0pt,#1](#2){#3};%
}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\[\left(\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2}\text{d}x\right)^2\mathrel{\tikznode{eq}{$=$}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2-y^2}\text{d}x\text{d}y
\]
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
  \draw[stealth'-,shorten <=2pt,rounded corners]
    (eq) |- ++(-0.9,-0.5) -- ++(0,-.5) node[below] {explanation};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in [frougon's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/581959), `tikzmark` can be used here. However, I think one should also make sure that the annotation does not overlap with the text. So one may want to put the `tikzpicture` inside the equation, measure the relevant distance and add it.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,tikzmark}

\newcommand{\diff}{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}}

\begin{document}
Some text before the equation.
\[ \left( \,\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty \mathrm{e}^{-x^2} \diff x \right)^{2}
   \tikzmarknode{eqsign}{=}
   \int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty  \int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty 
   \mathrm{e}^{-x^2-y^2} \diff x \diff y 
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,baseline={(tmp.base)}]
  \node(tmp){\vphantom{1}};
  \draw[latex-, overlay] (eqsign.south)  |- ++(-1,-0.7) -- ++ (0,-0.5)
            node[below] (expl) {explanation};
  % add point to tikzpicture to make it take the right size, subtract inner sep     
  \path ([yshift=2pt]expl.south-|tmp);
\end{tikzpicture}
\]
Some more text after the equation.
\end{document}
```