# How can you change te arrow tip 'style'

Tags: diagrams, arrows

I'm working on overleaf and I'm trying to duplicate this diagram[image]

But I can't find any way to obtain the upper arrow tip style or even match the lengths.
This is the closest code i obtained so far:`\begin{align*} Co&ng(\Lambda)\longleftrightarrow\Con{\Lambda} \\ &\equiv\longleftrightarrow\mathcal{C} \end{align*}`
but it gives me this
[image]

Comment: Have you seen this long discussion?
https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5461/is-it-possible-to-change-the-size-of-an-arrowhead-in-tikz-pgf/161238#161238
(it uses tikz, but that can be used in-line as well)

Comment: @johaschn yes, but I'm not well-versed in using tikz/tikzcd yet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ti*k*Z is the way to go there:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation} 
\begin{gathered}
\mathrm{Cong}(\Lambda)\ \tikz[baseline=-0.75ex]\draw[{Latex[length=3pt]}-{Latex[length=3pt]}] (0,0) -- +(0.75,0);\ \mathbb C(\Lambda) \\
\equiv\ \tikz[baseline=-0.75ex]\draw[{Straight Barb[length=5pt,width=5pt]}-{Straight Barb[length=5pt,width=5pt]}] (0,0) -- +(1.25,0);\ \mathcal C
\end{gathered}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

This uses the `\tikz` command to draw a single inline arrow in each of the two lines. The option `baseline=-0.75ex` passed to `\tikz` raises the arrow (try leaving it out to see what the effect is!).

Arrows are basically drawn using `\draw[<->]`, but instead of `<` and `>` I select appropriate arrow tips from the `arrows.meta` Ti*k*Z library: the `Latex` tip for the first arrow, and the `Straight Barb` tip for the second (see [p. 212 of the humongous Ti*k*Z manual](https://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf#page=212) for more information and more arrow tips). Each arrow tip also gets some options passed to it to control its length and width; this also makes it necessary to enclose the whole tip specification in braces, so you end up with specifications like `{Latex[length=3pt]}-{Latex[length=3pt]}` --- looks frightening at first glance, but it really just means "a double-ended arrow with `Latex` tips of length `3pt` on either side, please".

The rest is self-explanatory, I hope. You can make the arrows longer (or shorter) by changing adjusting the distance to which they're drawn, e.g. from `(0,0) -- +(0.75,0)` (that's 0.75cm) for the first to something different. If you want to raise or lower them, adjust the baseline, as described above. To change the tips, adjust their options, or pass new options to them.

If you need arrows like these more than once, it would probably be a good idea to define appropriate arrow tips and then use those throughout, or (better yet) define commands for the arrows themselves.

Finally -- just to give a few more tips --, the `gathered` environment is used here to have both lines of the `equation` centered, and `\mathrm` is used to typeset "Cong" using an upright font rather than the default italic. (Also, to typeset multi-letter identifiers and names in math mode, it's best to use `\mathit`, e.g. `\mathit{Cong}`; writing just `Cong` typesets the individual letters in a way that's appropriate for the product of single-letter variables, rather than a single multi-letter variable.)

**EDIT:** here's a snippet where both arrows are defined as new commands instead:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\DeclareMathOperator{\arrowOne}{\tikz[baseline=-0.75ex]\draw[{Latex[length=3pt]}-{Latex[length=3pt]}] (0,0) -- +(0.75,0);}
\DeclareMathOperator{\arrowTwo}{\tikz[baseline=-0.75ex]\draw[{Straight Barb[length=5pt,width=5pt]}-{Straight Barb[length=5pt,width=5pt]}] (0,0) -- +(1.25,0);}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation} 
\begin{gathered}
\mathrm{Cong}(\Lambda) \arrowOne \mathbb C(\Lambda) \\
\equiv \arrowTwo \mathcal C
\end{gathered}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

I've called them `\arrowOne` and `\arrowTwo`, for lack of a better name; functionally they're identical to the above. Using `\DeclareMathOperator` will also ensure correct spacing, so there's no need to manually use `\`  anymore here. (In principle you could also use `\mathop` directly for this, but `\DeclareMathOperator` is preferred; see [*What is the difference of \mathop, \operatorname and \DeclareMathOperator?*](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/84308/158639)).

To define "one-sided" arrows, just leave out either of the arrow tips. If you write `\draw[{Latex[length=3pt]}-]`, for instance, Ti*k*Z will only draw the left tip, giving you a "come-from" kind of arrow. If you need the vertical bar that `\mapsto` has, you can just add a second `\draw` command to the `\tikz` invocation:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareMathOperator{\comefrom}{\tikz[baseline=-0.5ex]{\draw[{Latex[length=3pt]}-] (0,0) -- +(0.75,0);\draw (0.75,0.05) -- +(0,-0.1);}}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation} 
x \comefrom y
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You'll probably want to play around with `baseline` etc. there; it may also be worth putting rounded caps on the lines drawn there, rather than square ones. In any case, the only real caveat here is that since you've got two `\draw` commands, you'll have to wrap them both in braces so that `\tikz` will in fact see and interpret both.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Yes, this pretty much solves my problem, though, I'm curious on how to define arrows as commands, because I'd like to have the 'solid black' arrow tip for a \mapsto arrow and also a \leftmapsto o \mapsfrom arrow

Comment: @ArmandoRosas Glad to hear it helped. I've amended my post with some more info for you.