# Equivalent of \ker for the image of a map

Tags: math-mode

I know I can use `\ker` in place of `\text{ker}` to denote the kernel of a map. Is there a similar command for the image of a map?

Even if I define my own command like

```
\newcommand{\Ima}{\text{Im}}
```

Inside the theorem environment (for example) I get the italic version of *Im*. How can I fix this?

Comment: I always thought this was a huge oversight; even `amsmath` doesn't define it.  The package does seem to have a bit of a bias toward calculus, somehow.

Comment: @Ryan: I think part of the issue is that `Im` for image is less universal than `ker` for kernel, perhaps because `Im` can also be used to denote the imaginary part of a complex number.

Comment: actually, `\Im` is already defined (in both plain tex and latex) to be a fraktur "I", so `\newcommand` won't work.

Comment: are these any help: [Define additional math operators to be typeset in roman](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/671), [How can I define a math operator behaving like \lim?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13554/), [How do I do a one-shot MathOperator?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12653/), ...

Comment: @Abramodj: Why capitalize Im and not ker?

Comment: @BrunoLeFloch: There's not any proper reason... I just always did it like that by hand

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You can use `\DeclareMathOperator` from the `amsmath` package to define it; in this way it will have the appropriate spacing and font:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\DeclareMathOperator{\Ima}{Im}

\begin{document}

$\Ima f\subseteq \ker g$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that's great and it will be useful in many other cases!