# Use 'Limits' on arbitrary math symbol

Tags: math-mode

In set theory, the union of an arbitrary number of sets can be taken:

```
\[ A_1 \cup A_2 \cup A_3 \cup \dots \cup A_k = \cup\limits_{i=1}^{k} A_i\]
```

I want to set the limits as they appear in `\[\sum_{i=1}^{k}\]`, however even in block equations, they do not show as limits.

Is this possible for an arbitrary math-mode symbol?

Comment: to show tex output make a screenshot locally and upload an image, we do not have mathjax running as is used on the math site.

Comment: there is a `\bigcup` designed for this use

Comment: Thanks, didn't realise the difference. Is there a way to do it arbitrarily though? Or are there any cases where it would be needed that it isn't already available?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How do I do a one-shot MathOperator?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12653/5764)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]

there is a bigcup operator for this use, or in general you can use `\mathop` around any math expression which gives it operator spacing and limits behaviour for superscripts, however doesn't make it larger in displaystyle as `\sum` and `\bigcup` are.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}


\[ A_1 \cup A_2 \cup A_3 \cup \dots \cup A_k = \bigcup_{i=1}^{k} A_i\]


\[ A_1 \cup A_2 \cup A_3 \cup \dots \cup A_k = \mathop{\cup}_{i=1}^{k} A_i\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: It could be worthwhile to remark, for the benefit of user who could read this answer in the future, that the authors of LaTeX followed this naming scheme consistently: `\cup`->`\bigcup`, `\cap`->`\bigcap`, `\oplus`->`\bigoplus`, `\otimes`->`\bigotimes`, etc. etc.  There are exceptions, however, as in `+`->`\sum` ;-)

Comment: @GustavoMezzetti actually all those names come from plain TeX so Donald Knuth

Comment: Well, yes, I knew! :-)  **Edit:** It was not Don Knuth who wrote this answer, though! ;-)