# How to put words under and above a math symbol in latex?

Tags: math-mode

I have already used `\sum` symbol for another reason, I needed an additional symbol and I have used `\Xi`, but the problem is I cannot put the super/sub scripts directly under or above like `\sum` or `\prod`. `\displaystyle` does not work here. Does anyone have any solution? Alternatively one may try to answer different but related question [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/411933/what-is-the-proper-latex-math-symbol-for-matrix-vertical-horizontal-concatenatio?noredirect=1#comment1028388_411933)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
{W}^k=\Big(\Xi_{s=1}^{S}\prod_{i=1}^{I}{}\Big)
\end{equation}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You're interested in [How do I do a one-shot math operator?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12653/5764)

Comment: also use `\Bigl(` and `\Bigr)` never just `\Big`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle why is that?

Comment: @Stephan because you get correct (mathopen/mathclose) spacing with bigl and bigr and incorrect (mathord) spacing with big.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A variation on https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/394934/4427

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\bigXi}{%
  \DOTSB\mathop{\mathpalette\bigXi@do\relax}\slimits@
}
\newcommand\bigXi@do[2]{%
  \vcenter{\hbox{%
    \sbox\z@{$#1\sum$}%
    \resizebox{!}{0.9\dimexpr\ht\z@+\dp\z@}{\raisebox{\depth}{$\m@th#1\Xi$}}%
  }}%
  \vphantom{\sum}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\[
W^k=\Bigl(\bigXi_{s=1}^{S}\prod_{i=1}^{I}{}\Bigr)
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]